# Advanced excel iteration function based on value

Tags: excel

Suppose you have two cells in excel, one is text which asks a user to enter a value in the adjacent cell, the value represents the quantity of something, for example, flowers.
Based on the quantity of flowers the user enters, subsequent questions are asked for each specific flower, for example if the user enters quantity of 2 flowers: how many petal does flower 1 have and how many petals does flower 2 have?

I need some way to structurally handle any number of flowers the user enters.

For example, if the user entered 0, this result should be calculated: null
if the user entered 1, this result should be calculated: how many petals does flower (1) have?
if the user entered 2, this result should be calculated: how many petals does flower (1) have?
how many petals does flower (2) have?
if the user entered 3, this result should be calculated: how many petals does flower (1) have? how many petals does flower (2) have? how many petals does flower (3) have?

I'm looking for the most robust structure possible to represent this in, I realize there are many "ghetto" solutions that could work for special cases.

Here is a screenshot of some inputs and results that I hand-made, I'm trying to find a way to automatically do this through a formula.

However!! I am not looking for something which merely only works for 1, 2, or 3 flowers. I need something which works for all positive numbers (robust/rigid way of doing it). At the same, as elegant as possible is great too (built-in excel formula rather than elaborate VBA script). An answer like "it isn't possible without VBA" would also be helpful if true.

[image]

[image: http://i.imgur.com/qEvhjIg.png]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need the 'ROW' and 'CONCATENATE' functions!

Paste the following formula in cell A2 and copy it down until you hit some maximum number of flowers:

```
=IF(ROW(A2)-1 > $B$2, "", CONCATENATE("How many petals does flower (", ROW(A2)-1, ") have?"))
```

This formula checks if the current row is larger than the number of flowers we're interested in. If it is, it prints a blank string (the ""). If the row number is less than that, it prints the question with the right number there.

If you're concerned about somebody typing a number greater than the number of cells you've copied it down through (say 10), you could add something like this in cell C1:

```
=IF(B2 > 10, "Too many flowers!")
```